# Is conditional expectation of the error of best linear predictor given $X$ is $0$ (Is it true that $y = a^*+b^*x + \eta$, where $E[\eta|x]=0$)?

Tags: probability, statistics, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

For simplicity, assume we are working with simple regression where the predictor $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

First write $y=E[y \mid x]+u$, where the variance of $u$ is a constant, and $E[u|x]=0$. I understand $E(y \mid x)$ minimizes the mean square prediction error (MSPE). We call $E[y \mid x]$ the true regression.

I understand the best (simple) linear prediction is
$$
a^*+b^* x=\left(E(y)-\frac{\operatorname{cov}(y, x)}{\operatorname{var}(x)} E(x)\right)+\frac{\operatorname{cov}(y, x)}{\operatorname{var}(x)} x
$$

Clearly, $E[y - (a^*+b^*x))] = 0 $. Equivalently, if I write $y = a^*+b^*x + \eta$, I can say $E[\eta] = 0$.

My question is whether or not $E[\eta| x] = 0$, which is a stronger statement.

I understand $a^*+b^*x$ is the projection of $y$ onto the linear function space of $x$. I think due to $E[u|x]=0$, I can also say $a^*+b^*x$ is the projection of $E[y|x]$ onto the linear function space of $x$.

Eventually I'm curious about: denote the underlying model as $y=E[y \mid x]+u$, where $E[u|x]=0$. If we are dealing with linear working model, and find the best linear predictor $a^*+b^*x$, Is it true that $y = a^*+b^*x + \eta$, where $E[\eta|x]=0$? (sure I understand it is not minimizing the MSPE).

Update:

When the true regression $E[y|x]$ is not linear, the model $y = a^*+b^*x + \eta$ does not have the property $E[\eta|x]=0$. When one is optimizing over the model $y = a+bx + \eta$ with $E[\eta|x]=0$, they are implicitly assuming that the true regression $E[y|x]$ is a linear model. This argument can be seen from the proof of the conditional expectation is the unique minimizer of MSPE.

Comment: You have started with $E[u \mid x]=0$.  Are you also assuming that $u$ is independent of $x$ or at least $E[u^2 \mid x]$ is constant, i.e. homoscedasticity?

Comment: @Henry By proposition 1.4.1 in Mathematical Statistics Volume I Bickle, from the $y=E[y|x] + u$, I understand $u$ is uncorrelated with any function of $x$. I'm not making additional assumption $u$ is independent of $x$ or homoscedasticity. But I haven't thought about why I need them. Do you mind explaining a little bit more? Thanks!

Comment: $u$ being uncorrelated with any function of $x$ does not imply that $u^2$ is uncorrelated with $x$.  For example consider $u=\pm x$ with equal probability.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for pointing out. I have checked the definition of homoscedasticity. Since I assume $(x_i,y_i)$ are i.i.d copies of $(x,y)$, which follows the data generating process $y=E[y|x]+u$, where the variance of $u$ is a constant. I implicitly assume homoscedasticity.

Comment: when you assume $E(\eta|x)=0$, then $x$ and $\eta$ will be orthognal in mean, so that a [linear] project onto $x$ becomes meaningful in the sense that one has the standard meaning for $\partial E(y|x) / \partial x$ as a so-called partial effect.

Comment: @Math-fun Thank you for your help. What I'm guessing (but not sure, therefore I asked in this post) is that I may not need to impose the assumption $[\eta|x]=0$ to conclude what you said. If $a^*+b^*x$ is the best linear predictor, then would it naturally lead to $E[\eta|x]=0$, and therefore meaningful interpretation follows?

Comment: You are welcome! The problem is the formulation: if $a^*+b^*x$ is the best linear predictor, then it should predict using x only, this is while if $x$ and $\eta$ are not orthogonal, then observing $x$ discloses some info about $\eta$ too, so that the prediction does not reflect the partial change in $E(y|x)$ due a "sole change" in $x$ - as anova is desiged to reach.